# bitmapfileheader - how are the bits being read?

Tags: c, image, bitmap, endianness, bmp

My questions is with how the bits are organized in a BITMAPFILEHEADER.

I have the following image below.

[image: smiley.bmp]

If I look at the header of the image I get the following sequence of bits.

```
424df6 000000 000000 003600 0000

(2 bytes) 42 4d bftype - (BM) as expected.
(4 bytes) f6 00 00 00 bfsize - the size is 246 bytes.
(2 bytes) 00 00 bfReserved1 - must be 0.
(2 bytes) 00 00 bfReserved2 - must be 0.
(4 bytes) 36 00 00 00 bfOffBits - should be 56.
```

My question is how are those bits being read? If bfsize is a DWORD (32 bits - 4 bytes), shouldnt 246 be represented as 00 00 00 F6? The same could be said with bfOffBits.

Comment: Read about [*ednainness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg beat me by 2 secs ;)

Comment: Also, it will be much simpler if you just create (or use an existing) structure for the header, and read the structure as a single entity.

Comment: Thank you. On to it now.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg should be answer.